# Can't iterate through std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

Since I've started to using `std::map` I've started to receive assertion error whenever I click on the button. I want to clear all the contents inside `my_map` and start adding again everytime I click the button.

**my.cpp**

```
typedef std::map<str, MyClass> mapper;
mapper my_map;

void add_map(const str& name, MyClass* l) { /...../ }

void invoke_me()
{
```

Here I initialized variable `i` with the size of `my_map`, however, it returns the previous size before it was cleared

```
    int i = my_map.size(); // i = 4, my_map.size() = 1

    if (!my_map.empty())
    {
        for (const auto& it : map)
        {
            // Assert error: map/set iterator not incrementable
            const MyClass& l = it.second;
            l.on_clicked();
        }
    }
}
// cont'd
```

This should do the neat clearing of `my_map`, but I don't think it's doing the right job

```
void clear_map()
{
    my_map.clear();
}
```

**implementor.h**

```
struct MyClass
{
    std::function<void()> on_clicked;
};
```

**implementor.cpp**

```
MyClass button;

button.on_clicked = [&] {
    clear_map();
    add_map("MyButton", &button);
};
```

Well actually on_click is a callback, and it has to be called through the `invoke_me` function

**main.cpp**

```
while (RUNNING)
    invoke_me();
```

I would say that it is because of incorrect map size that's why the it keeps looping even if it's out of bounds, or maybe I'd corrupted or messed up that map.

Comment: Did you mean `for (const auto& it : my_map)`? You don't need to check if the map is empty before the for loop. A short complete example of real code would go a long way to helping us help you. There are several common mistakes that could cause the same symptoms you're seeing, but it's hard to tell with just fragments.

Comment: *it returns the previous size before it was cleared* It is impossible. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: I made `my_map` as a global variable instead of a member class variable because I don't want it to be reset.

Comment: There's a strange mismatch of pointers and instances in use here too. If your map stores instances then you probably made a copy of the object you passed the pointer to. *shrug* The edit didn't really add any clarity.

Comment: Is `button` maybe going out of scope before it's used in `on_clicked`? You're capturing by reference and then are making a copy of it when adding it to the map.

Comment: @MillieSmith I'd guess either something is going out of scope, or there's a copy of something being made unintentionally, but the code contradicts itself. The for loop won't compile so I know it's not actual copy/pasted code, and "Well actually on_click is a callback, and it has to be called through the invoke_me function" doesn't match up with that code either.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Check out my answer. I think I found the issue. And yeah, the code has quite a few oddities.

Answer (score 2):

There might be more issues, but this looks to be the main one:

```
button.on_clicked = [&] {
    clear_map();
    add_map("MyButton", &button);
};
```

You're clearing the map, and this function gets called while you're iterating:

```
for (const auto& it : my_map)
{
    // Assert error: map/set iterator not incrementable
    const MyClass& l = it.second;
    l.on_clicked();
}
```

Your iterators are being invalidated by the clear.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it if that's how the code actually works. Good guess, I hope it's right. :).